# Black Depth in Red-black Tree?

Tags: trees, data-structure

Wikipedia's [Red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) states the last property of a Red-black tree:

> Every path from a given node to any of its descendant NIL nodes contains the same number of black nodes. Some definitions: the number of black nodes from the root to a node is the node's black depth; the uniform number of black nodes in all paths from root to the leaves is called the black-height of the red–black tree

I'm not understanding this property. So, looking at this tree from the above Wikipedia article:

[image]

What is this field's value for the `8` tree, i.e. `Root (13) -> 8`?

How about for `15`, i.e. `Root (13) -> 7 -> 15`?

When providing an answer, please also explain the why of that number.

Comment: The definition you quote concerns "Every path from a given node to any of  its descendant NIL nodes", but you ask about "this field's value" for paths `13 -> 8` and `13 -> 7 -> 15` that are not of such a form.  I'm not sure what you are asking.  Probably you meant `17` in place of `7`.

Answer (score 0):

In red-black tree you know: that *black-depth* is permanent for every two child in the tree.
For example:

***8***:

We have two *children's* $1$ and $11$ and for them we know that *black-depth*($1$) = *black-depth*($11$)=$2$.